# What is a normal limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, normal-families

I have a question that asks me to show that if a normal family has only one normal limit, then it converges. What is a normal limit?

Comment: How have you tried to look up the answer?

Comment: Yes I have, I have not seen this terminology anywhere

Comment: You are right.  (The phrase "normal limit" occurs widely in many non-mathematical contexts.) But maybe read about normal families.

Comment: This question has a definition at the end: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734180/convergence-theorem-for-power-series-radius-of-convergence-and-normal-converge